# How to get TAILS live USB to boot

Tags: live-usb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I have Windows 8.1 on UEFI BIOS (Toshiba Satellite) and have allowed Ubuntu to install it's dual boot option, which is GNU GRUB (version 2.0~beta2-9ubuntu1) .

I have used my USB / TAILS successfully on another computer, albeit a different BIOS / manufacturer – Gateway (UEFI/LEGACY BIOS) options, so I know the USB drive works and boots to TAILS just great.

However on the Toshiba I cannot get it to boot from the USB drive. What I attempted to do get it to work is using the command line because the GNU GRUB does not have an option to boot from CD or USB, correct?

So, from the command line I enter the following I borrowed from the standard loader script:

```
Insmod chain
Insmod gzio
Insmod ext2
Insmod part_gpt
Set root ='hd0,gpt1'
```

Then I run a 'find' command to verify that my USB device is the one set to root, and it appears that it did successfully.  I enter:
Find /[TAB KEY]

My ouput is:

```
Possible files are:
.disk/  efi/  live/  tmo/  utils/  syslinux/  System Volume Information
```

Now to enter the chainloader command I found for UEFI-type BIOS:

```
Chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
```

Here is my output:

```
File path /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(0,14)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,22,4e1fde, 91246…4,2,2)/File(\efi\boot)/File(bootx64.efi)/EndEntire
```

So now I'm stuck. Please kindly advise.

Comment: I think you came pretty far, the only thing you would need to do is to boot the binary with the `boot` command in the shell, this also left me puzzled at times.

Answer (score 1):

Enter to the BIOS and change the boot system from UEFI to Legacy, and make the USB stick available to boot.

This doesn't have anything to do with GRUB.

Comment: "Switch from UEFI to Legacy"… if there only was this option. Manufacturers started making systems some time ago where legacy boot isn't supported any more.